list vs direct aggregate initialization of implicitly initialized fields
If we contrast list initialization of an aggregate and direct initialization of an aggregate, if I don't specify initializers for all fields, then I suppose the following applies:

For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly initialized element is initialized as follows:

If the element has a default member initializer, the element is initialized from that initializer.
(since C++11)
Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list.
Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

otherwise, if the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified)
aggregate class, it is initialized as described in aggregate
initialization except that narrowing conversions are permitted,
designated initializers are not allowed, a temporary bound to a
reference does not have its lifetime extended, there is no brace
elision, and any elements without an initializer are
value-initialized.

My question is, what is the difference between copy initialization from an empty initializer list and value-initialization? Maybe a change of language would be in order?

One difference would be that value-initialization could not call an initializer-list constructor in the same way copy-init from {} could:
struct A {
    A(std::initializer_list<int>);
};

struct B {
    int i;
    A a;
};

B b1{ 1 };  // OK: `B{ 1, {} }`, or `B{ 1, A(std::initializer_list<int>{}) }`
// B b2(1);  // Error: Cannot value-init an A, it has no default constructor
B b3(1, {});  // Works when copying from `{}`

It appears that GCC/MSVC don't implement this properly, but clang does: https://godbolt.org/z/nj1frf9xv

can you make it into an online example?

You need to fix your example to use an empty initializer list.

An aggregate may not have any user declared constructors, though

@AndyG Yes B is an aggregate

@BrianBi This question is about how elements of an aggregate without an initializer are initialized

I definitely slapped my forehead after realizing you were initializing B and not A in the code sample.

@Artyer can you report a gcc bug, please?
